# PHP decode JSON get uname?

Tags: php, json

How do I get the uname value from this JSON into PHP variable? to use through my page?

```
    {
        "token": "iutiutiut-0jjjjj0-97987g",
        "auth": {
            "id": 1,
            "app_id": 1,
            "user": {
                "uname": "foo",  
                "role": "member"
            }
    }
}
```

thanks for some reason just can't get it and I can't find examples similar anywhere on google or I am not calling it correctly.

could you also tell me the correct terminology so I know as well thanks

Comment: Which part are you having problems with? Decoding the JSON, or posting the data to PHP?

Comment: im sorry decoding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is decode JSON. PHP has a built in function for this aptly named... [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Assuming your JSON is a string (`$json_string`), here is how you would decode it:

```
$obj = json_decode($json_string);
$uname = $obj->auth->user->uname;
```

Or, if you prefer the array syntax, use the second argument in `json_decode`:

```
$arr = json_decode($json_string, true);
$uname = $obj['auth']['user']['uname'];
```

Comment: thank you i actually see my mistake  i had it set up to encode " json_encode($cexecute,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);"    and that is what was tossing it off .  Thank you